# get "undefined" when triyng to use $.get()

Tags: jquery, arrays

When I try to use API for coingecko I get undefined in console log. Why and what the problem in my code? I don't care about looping now I want just get a result?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styyley.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="clist">
        <p></p>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqu.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false",function (data){
            
        var c = data.id;
            console.log(c)



    });
});
```

Comment: We may need to see the *full* error message to make a conclusive answer, but in a quick peek, are you trying to use jQuery without importing jQuery?

Comment: @Alejandro That would display a TypeError: '$' is not defined.

Comment: I would use `console.log(data)` and/or `console.log(typeof data)`. It's likely you're getting back a string, which does not have an `id` property, and need to parse it first (i.e., `var parsed = JSON.parse(data);`).

Answer (score 0):

Simply going to: `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false`
Shows me that the response is an array.

So you probably looking to something like this:

```
for (let i in data) {
  coin = data[i];
  console.log(coin.id);
}
```